# How to copy/paste parts of a text in Messages.app

Tags: macos, messages

I am pretty sure I used to be able to select and copy text in Messages.app like in any other app (click + drag, double-click, etc.)

Right now I don't seem to be able to do this.

I am not sure what updated last, I am on macOS 10.14.6, Messages.app 12.0

Use case:

[image]

How do I copy the code from the message?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug.

I restarted Messages.app and now it works as expected (and as it should have done in the first place)

[image]

I'll keep an eye out and edit this answer if I figure out what causes the bug.

Comment: Restarting an app and/or the system is the first step in troubleshooting an issue and should've been done before posting the question to begin with!

Answer (score 2):

It does have an odd behaviour, but one that's easy to work round.

If you click-hold, the 'reaction' pop-up will appear, so the trick is just a short click.

If you click once straight onto the message bubble, anywhere, the text goes grey. At this point any interaction is with the entire message. If you directly double click or right click whilst the text is initially black, it doesn't go to grey, you can interact directly.

Basically, *don't do that first click*. You can do anything else & it works as individual words - so right click, double-click or click-drag works, for instance.

If you click outside the message bubble, the text goes back to black & you can now interact like any ordinary text.

BTW, verification codes like that will be found by Safari & will click right into the web page.

**Examples**

- Grey text - handled as a single item for copy/paste.

[image]

- Black text, can be individually selected.

[image]

- Same in dark mode (first message is selected)

[image]

- Smart fill-in feature in Safari

[image]

Comment: Ah, indeed, the fact that clicking a bubble selects its whole content isn't all that obvious. The screenshot the OP included in the question shows an un-selected bubble actually, but maybe they click into the bubble first.

Comment: I can't do what this answer says to do. https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8OXC.gif

Comment: @the  how is right click shown in this GIF?

Comment: @ankii I don't right-click, although (see my answer) since restarting messages right-click works exactly as you describe. I don't know why your answer is downvoted.

Comment: @theonlygusti Maybe the edit on my answer allows and convinces the voter to change the vote.

Answer (score -1):

This answer assumes that you haven't clicked on the message to make it selected and thus light grey.

I do right click and it selects the word. Two finger single tap.

For a long sentence, click and drag to the destination word also works for me, at least.

Comment: If I right click it makes the whole message grey — not anymore (since restarting messages), looks like a bug. Your answer describes correct behaviour.

Comment: What is the cursor when you hover over the message.? If it's text, it should work, if it is arrow, you need to click outside the message to deselect the message first