# Messages app is popping up an emoji options when I try to copy the message

Tags: messages

I have tried a number of times to highlight a Messages App message on Macos to be able to copy it into the clipboard. Instead it continually pops up an emoji box:

[image]

Can that popup be disabled so I can copy the message contents into the clipboard?

Comment: Don't click-hold, just click. Relevant but not identical - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/371319/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin pls make that an answer.  i don't know why apple had to change normal behavior but yes doing the way you say gives the desired (/normal) behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amongst the unexpected behaviours displayed by Messages…

If you click-hold, the 'reaction' pop-up will appear, so the trick is just a short click.

The rest of the selection behaviour, for sake of completeness, copied from my answer at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/371319/85275

If you click once straight onto the message bubble, anywhere, the text goes grey. At this point any interaction is with the entire message. If you directly double click or right click whilst the text is initially black, it doesn't go to grey, you can interact directly.

Basically, *don't do that first click*. You can do anything else & it works as individual words - so right click, double-click or click-drag works, for instance.

If you click outside the message bubble, the text goes back to black & you can now interact like any ordinary text.

BTW, verification codes like that will be found by Safari & will click right into the web page.

**Examples**

- Grey text - handled as a single item for copy/paste.

  [image]
- Black text, can be individually selected.

  [image]
- Same in dark mode (first message is selected)

  [image]
- Smart fill-in feature in Safari

  [image]

Comment: crap, brain  fart, sorry deleted my comments.